# Can I build up a profilometry set up, to study the surface roughness of polymer fibres?

Tags: optics, laser, topology, polymers

I need to study the surface roughness of some fibres, I was told that the best way is the profilometer, but can I design and build up a set up of a profilometer?

Comment: I imagine it is far more expensive (time & equipment considered) to design & build & calibrate your own profilometer than buying a commercial one... Do you absolutely have to set it up yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no time to wait for a one to be delivered, and due to the economic state in my country, any price would be high. I have many components such as beam splitters, mirrors ... etc, would it be easy to build one with these components?

Comment: Ift you know optics and already have an optical lab it should be possible. It depends likely on what you have.  Perhaps you get an answer but you should look for a scheme at least

Comment: @ِAlchimista thanks, but do you have a schematic diagram for this system?

Comment: Try digging Google.  But then the premises are not so favourable, I would say.

Comment: could you please recommend me any other easy technique to study the topology of polymers?